# How can we log everything done by Net::Sftp in a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how to log every action of Net::Sftp into a file in ruby on rails for debugging and how can I log verbose::debug to a logfile.

```
    sftp = Net::SFTP.start(config[:host], config[:user], config[:options], verbose::debug)
    files_arr = []
    sftp.connect!
    sftp.dir.foreach(src_dir) do |entry|
      file_name = entry.name
      begin
        if entry.file? && (file_name.end_with?(".xml") || file_name.end_with?(".zip"))
          sftp.download!(File.join(src_dir, file_name), File.join(dest_dir, file_name))
          files_arr << file_name
        end
      rescue Exception => e
        next
      end
    end
    sftp.channel.eof!
    sftp.close_channel unless sftp.closed?
```

my objective is to log all that happens in this code to a file, how can I do it.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of what you're actually trying to do, with enough code for a minimally reproducible example. Ideally also the code you have at the moment and the specific errors or failures you encounter with it. Then, people can give you useful answers! (FWIW, you probably just want `Rails.logger`, which will write into the `/logs` directory.)

Comment: JohnP I have edited my question and added a sample code, added Rails.logger will write everything in the prod log which is very cumbersome to find, so I wanted to write it in a specific file.

Comment: The thing is that using `Rails.logger` in your code is just one line, and it ensures your log messages are time-stamped, chronological and consistently formatted. If you add a clear identifier for your messages (like "MyLogLine: foo") then you can quickly search for them in any text editor. And, if you want to have verbose logs, that's pretty much exactly what `Rails.logger` was designed for! Plus, if you want to point it to a specific file location, you can configure `Rails.logger` to do that. Don't reinvent the wheel when Rails has one ready for you.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want, is to log all the info of the above code section to a different log file and not the standard development.log or production.log. so what will be the config of `Rails.logger` Do you have a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the comments, it seems that what you want is to define a custom logger that you can then use to log your custom info to its own file. Something like this in the relevant `environment.rb` should do what you need.

```rb
my_logger = Logger.new('log/my_logger.log')
my_logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

Then, you can add `my_logger 'MESSAGE'` at the relevant points in your code to add entries to your custom logfile.